# Why does this Java Robot code shutdown my computer?

Tags: java, automation, shutdown, awtrobot

I was fiddling with some code based on automation with the `java.awt.Robot` class. The code was running perfectly, but when I changed a few things, some of which did not even run with `main`, code seemed to partially finish it's task, but then the computer started its shutdown sequence, closing all of the programs. I was only able to stop it by clicking cancel on the "Waiting For..." screen. Do any of you have any idea why this code below could make this occur?

Again, this code worked perfectly before I added/removed/changed something.

I'm pasting it exactly as it is, incase there are any specific things causing this. Sorry for the long post.

```
package _defaultpackage;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

import static java.awt.event.InputEvent.*;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;//static import means we can type VK_1 instead of KeyEvent.VK_1

public class JavaRobot {

    static Robot robot;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {robot = new Robot();} catch (Exception e) {}

        robot.setAutoDelay(30);
        robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);

        combination(VK_WINDOWS, VK_R);

        paste("notepad");

        hit(VK_ENTER);

        paste("Hello World!\n123");

        robot.delay(2000);

        combination(VK_ALT, VK_F4);

        hit(VK_RIGHT);
        hit(VK_ENTER);

        robot.setAutoDelay(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 700; i++) {
            robot.mouseMove(i, i);
        }

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    static void leftClick() {
        robot.mousePress(BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(200);
        robot.mouseRelease(BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(200);
    }

    static void type(String s) {
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int code = b;
            // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
            if (code > 96 && code < 123)
                code = code - 32;
            //robot.delay(40);
            robot.keyPress(code);
            robot.keyRelease(code);
        }
    }

    static void hit(int i) {
        robot.keyPress(i);
        robot.keyRelease(i);
    }

    static void combination(int... i) {
        for (int a : i) {
            robot.keyPress(a);
        }
        for (int a : i) {
            robot.keyRelease(a);
        }
    }

    static void paste(String s) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(s), null);
        combination(VK_CONTROL, VK_V);

    }

    static void paste(String s, int delay) {//delay is additional delay after auto robot delay
        String[] letters = s.split("");
        for (String a : letters) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(a), null);
            combination(VK_CONTROL, VK_V);
            robot.delay(delay);
        }
    }

    static void pasteRestore(String s) {
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable save = clipboard.getContents(null);
        clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(s), null);
        combination(VK_CONTROL, VK_V);
        clipboard.setContents(save, null);

    }

    static void pasteRestore(String s, int delay) {
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable save = clipboard.getContents(null);

        String[] letters = s.split("");
        for (String a : letters) {
            clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(a), null);
            combination(VK_CONTROL, VK_V);
        }
        clipboard.setContents(save, null);

    }




}
```

Comment: If no application window is active, ALT F4 will shutdown windows.

Comment: @assylias that makes sense, but what would make the notepad window lose focus?

Comment: Perhaps you're sending a wrong key-code by mistake, like ALT-TAB. Remove/comment out the ALT-F4 and everything after it, and add a delay between keypresses (for easier testing), and run it, and see what it does.

Comment: Also, `catch(Exception e) {}` is pure evil.

Comment: @immibis I did what you said, and it seems that randomly and not super commonly, the notepad window doesn't gain focus and appears in the background. It is very strange behavior. Thanks for the help though! I'd mark a comment as "best answer" if I could, but I can't :/

Comment: @Starwarswii It's not an answer, though. (Also, if no answer answers your question, note that you are not required to select one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the bug is in method `combination()`. Take a look on it again:

```
static void combination(int... i) {
    for (int a : i) {
        robot.keyPress(a);
    }
    for (int a : i) {
        robot.keyRelease(a);
    }
}
```

When pressing Alt-f4 user is expected to

1. press Alt,
2. press F4
3. release F4
4. release Alt.

In your case the order of releases is the same a s order of presses. So, I'd try to re-write this method as following:

```
static void combination(int... c) {
    for (int a : c) {
        robot.keyPress(a);
    }
    for (int i = c.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        robot.keyRelease(c[i]);
    }
}
```

Try it. I hope this will work.

Additionally pay attention on these lines:

```
robot.setAutoDelay(30);
robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
```

I personally never used these setters. Try to work without them. Accroding to my experience when closing windows you do not really need delay. Everything works without delay and even faster. The point is in correct order of events that you generate.

Comment: As @assylias explained above, the Alt-F4 command is what's shutting down the computer, due to a lack of window focus. Do you think that pressing the key combination in the order that I did would cause some sort of window unfocusing? I'm not sure, as all other examples of key combination on the web, as well as this website, show them in the order that I press them. If it does make a difference, why is the first key combination working just fine?

Comment: Yes, I do think so. Just try it and I'd be glad to know what do you get.

Comment: sorry if my above comment sounded defensive. Rereading it now, it sounds a little mean and challenging you, which was not how i meant it to sound at all.

Anyway, I tried it out, and It's hard to tell due to this problem I described above in the comments of the main thread of the notepad window sometimes not gaining focus immediately, but I think it _maybe_ helps, and thus I'm marking this answer as accepted. I realized that using an automated Alt-F4 probably wasn't a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Well, good luck with it. I really hope it will help. At least I always use this method (I mean releasing keys in reverse order) because it sounds more correct for me.